# What's the kind of cake that have liquid frosting that drips when you open the package?

Tags: baking, cake, frosting

I've seem videos of such cakes where the frosting is in molten/semi-liquid form sitting on top of the cake, and held up by packaging (usually a piece of hard plastic wrap around the cake). Upon lifting the wrap the frosting flows down and covers the cake, which is beautiful to watch.

I was searching hard on the internet but couldn't find the right keyword. What are these kind of cakes called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found it. they're called pull-me-up cakes or tsunami cakes or in my opinion quite ambiguously, doll cakes.